# C++ Array unexpected bug

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to make a simple programm that shows a square of 16 'X' and that you can change specific coordinates.
Everything is finished and i dont get any bugreports but in the programm things are very strange.
what i should get is easy

```
 XXXX                              
 XXXX
 XXXX
 XXXX
```

and if i change 1,1 to A i should have this

```
 AXXX
 XXXX
 XXXX
 XXXX
```

but what i see when i run the program is this:

```
 XXXX
 XXXX
 XXXX
 @
```

well what is with the fourth line? there is a smiley in the first spot (i used an @) and the rest is empty.
when i change 1,1 to anything, 3,4 changes too.
everything else works properly.
and if i try to change something in the fourth line the program crashes.
if you want to test it yourself i can upload the .exe
    #include

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (;;) {
    int eingabe1;
    int eingabe2;
    char neueingabe;
    char array[4][4];
    array[1][1] = 'X';
    array[1][2] = 'X';
    array[1][3] = 'X';
    array[1][4] = 'X';
    array[2][1] = 'X';
    array[2][2] = 'X';
    array[2][3] = 'X';
    array[2][4] = 'X';
    array[3][1] = 'X';
    array[3][2] = 'X';   
    array[3][3] = 'X';
    array[3][4] = 'X';
    array[4][1] = 'X';
    array[4][2] = 'X';
    array[4][3] = 'X';
    array[4][4] = 'X';
    cout << "koordinaten eingeben" << endl; 
    cin >> eingabe1;
    cin >> eingabe2;
    cout << array[eingabe1][eingabe2] << endl;
    cout << "neueingabe eingeben" << endl;
    cin >> neueingabe;
    array[eingabe1][eingabe2] = neueingabe;
    cout << array[eingabe1][eingabe2]<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i hope you can help

Comment: Arrays in C, C++ *et al* use indices starting at 0.

Comment: You should start by reading some [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), really.

Comment: you make me feel so stupid with 1 line :D

Comment: thats just what im doing.

Comment: Also note that "bug reports" generally come from humans, or other entities *testing* your software. The compiler can only generate warnings and errors if your code doesn't comply with the language specifications, but it cannot tell you "it doesn't do what it should". The behavior you're describing is clearly a bug, so that's a bug report right there.

Answer (score 3):

**YOU ARE WRITING PAST YOUR ARRAY!**

Arrays in C/C++/C#/Java and most other languages start their numbering with 0.

So for

```
int arr[4];
// you have:
arr[0]=1;
arr[1]=2;
arr[2]=3;
arr[3]=4;
//arr[4]= A REALLY BIG ERROR;
```

Comment: WHY DO YOU WRITE IN CAPS?

Comment: I couldn't stress that sentence enough, sorry.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Hope I don't get -1'd for this stressing of mine (and yours)  ;)

Comment: well i actually deserver getting caps'd when i make such a mistake that someone even suggests me to read a book while thats what im doing

Comment: That's the reason why we should use `std::vector` in C++.

Comment: @skalli that's something completely different; both have their uses, some of them overlap, but not all

Comment: Of course there are reasons not to use `std::vector`. But there are no reasons to use a raw array. A `std::array` is a viable alternative in this case.

Comment: in Smalltalk, most arrays start at 1

Answer (score 1):

Start the indices at 0. So the max index is 3,3; the lowest is 0,0. Accessing other values leads to random behavior - in the best case it crashes your program.